# cx_Oracle: XML and LONG data type - has same definition in cx_Oracle

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

When processing Oracle data, in order to read XML type - we use GetClobVal() function in Oracle.
For LONG data type - no need.
The issue is, that in cx_Oracle module for python, both are defined as DB_TYPE_LONG.
This prevent to automatically read the data with/without GetClobVal for LONG and XML.
Is there is know way to distinguish between LONG and XML in python/cx_Oracle ?

Comment: Share what you are trying to achieve and where you are trying to compare types.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/ReturnLobsAsStrings.py